# Permanently change @INC for Perl scripts

Tags: perl, google-cloud-platform, debian

I have a VM (Debian 9), running on Google Cloud Platform.
I need to add some folder to `@INC` to normally execute my Perl scripts. I've tried to do something like this:

```
export PERLLIB=/path/to/my/dir
```

or

```
PERL5LIB=/path/to/my/dir
```

but this works only for my current SSH session. When I close browser window and connect again I get old `@INC` path.

How to do this permanently? Or maybe there are some other ways to do this?

**P.S.** Ways like this:

```
perl -I/path/to/my/dir program.pl
```

or this:

```
push @INC, '/path/to/my/dir/';
```

are not sutable for me, because I want to easily call scripts, and dont want to modify their content.

Comment: Add the `export PERL5LIB=...` to your `.profile` or `.bashrc` (or the corresponding file for your shell).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, just setting environment variables like `PERL5LIB` and `PERLLIB` will only affect your current shell session. When you log out and log back in again, those settings will have been wiped out.

So the next step is to make those settings more permanent by setting them automatically each time you log in to the system. You do this by adding your changes to your `.bashrc` or `.profile` files (depending on which shell you are using). These files are executed each time you log in to the system, so anything you add there will be available for every login session.

However, there's one additional potential complication. You say that this system is running in the Google Cloud Platform. It seems likely to me, therefore, that you have a virtual machine or container-based system which is rebuilt or reset frequently. In that case, in order for your changes to be truly permanent, you'll need to add them to whatever mechanisms you use to build your VMs or containers. Perhaps that's a Puppet manifest, a Chef recipe or something like that. Without knowing how your system is built, it's hard to give any concrete advice.

Comment: Thx! And if I want to run scripts from browser (cgi), this option will not work?

Comment: @adrenalin: I'm not sure why you'd think that. Even a CGI process is owned by a user. And every user can have a `.bashrc` or `.profile`.